# A difference between “de manière” and “d'une manière”?

Tags: articles

> Paraître / sembler : employé avec un adjectif, paraître décrit **de manière neutre** l’aspect, l’apparence : il paraît jeune (et il l’est, pour autant qu’on sache). Sembler laisse entendre que la réalité pourrait ne pas correspondre à l’apparence : il semble jeune (mais peut-être est-il plus vieux qu’il ne paraît).
>
> from the Larousse

I ask myself what's the difference between "de manière" and "d'une manière". I really think there is one.

Could it have been "d'une manière neutre"?
I look forward to your replies!

#### PS:

Upon reflection, there is an analogy in the situation of adjectives too.

For example:
*une voiture de sport* = *a sports car*
(but you don't normally say "une voiture sportive").

Another example in English:

- a logical error = an error made logically (which sounds a bit strange)
- a logic error = an error which involves logic

So my guess is that the difference between “de manière” and “d'une manière” is something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

***de** manière* neutre : *manière* est utilisée dans son acception générale, manière est ici la façon, la forme utilisée pour accomplir cette action : on a utilisé la *manière neutre*, *le principe* de neutralité (pas d'article non plus devant *neutralité*, on reste dans les définitions générales).

***d'une** manière* neutre : ici on utilise une façon *particulière* pour accomplir une action, mais on aurait pu en envisager une autre : on a utilisé *une manière neutre*, *l'outil* de la neutralité (l'article est aussi devant *neutralité*, on précise la définition et son application précise).

On pourrait insister en précisant : *De la manière la plus neutre possible*.

> "C'est une *voiture de sport*".

... est tout à fait correct et conseillé pour l'écrit et les contextes soutenus. Mais le langage sportif ou mercantile utilise souvent :

> "C'est une *voiture sportive*" pour dire que la conduite de cette voiture peut être sportive,

et carrément, lorsqu'on est en face de l'objet (peut-être par anthropomorphisme):

> "C'est une sportive !".

Pour ce qui concerne la logique :

> - *Une erreur logique* est une erreur qui découle logiquement de la situation.
> - *Une erreur **de** logique*, est une erreur qui découle du raisonnement employé.

Du point de vue francophone, il n'y a pas vraiment de logique ou de cohésion entre les trois situations que vous présentez :

- *Manière* : le *de* différencie ce qui est d'ordre général et d'ordre particulier,
- *Voiture* : le *de* est correct mais peut s'éliminer dans le langage courant par facilité ou pour suivre les expressions à la mode,
- *Logique* : le *de* (ou son omission) est un pivot du raisonnement qui déplace l'origine de l'erreur.

Answer (score 0):

"De manière neutre" in this case seems to be serving literally as an "adverbe DE MANIÈRE" modifying the verb "décrire."

"Adverbes de manière" are usually formed by adding "ment" (ly) to adjectives, but when the adjective in question "neutre" (neutral) would sound too weird with the "ment" suffix "neutrement" (neutrally), the idiomatic form, "de manière + adjective," can serve as an adverb: "used with an adjective, "paraître" neutrally describes the appearance (of someone/something)."

Since this is an idiomatic/[collocation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_%28linguistique%29)al construction used to create adverbs from adjectives, I would say that "d'une manière neutre" would be less correct (or at least [less utilized according to Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de%20mani%C3%A8re%20neutre%2Cd%27une%20mani%C3%A8re%20neutre&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20mani%C3%A8re%20neutre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%27%20une%20mani%C3%A8re%20neutre%3B%2Cc0)) than "de manière neutre." (Please note that you will probably need to (re)click the blue "Search lots of books' button after the Ngram site loads)

However, [this Canadian government website](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_f&page=9nkqRcLdTCV8.html) asserts that the two forms are interchangeable (and even that "d'une" is more prevalent than "de," contrary to Ngram).

From my admittedly non-Francophone point of view, I personally detect the following nuance between the two forms, which is curiously similar to the nuance between "paraître" and "sembler" in the entry from Larousse that you cite in your question, and this nuance that I detect is why I think "de manière neutre" is more correct in the cited definition:

> "De manière neutre" = In a strictly neutral manner/fashion/way = (in the imperative form) “BE neutral!”
>
> "D'une manière neutre" = In a manner/fashion/way that is usually
>   associated with acting/being neutral (but doesn’t necessarily
>   guarantee one’s neutrality) = (in the imperative form) “ACT neutral!”